# Safari refuses to clear "Recently Closed" list

Tags: macos, safari

Using Safari 15.1 on macOS 10.15.7. When I clear history, for some reason there's one item in the "Recently Closed" list that keeps coming back. I even tried deleting "~/Library/Safari/History.db", and it looks like the item is gone, but then it comes right back again.

Anyone know what the heck is going on?

Comment: This could be a Safari iCloud History item from another device. Try turning off iCloud for Safari on all of your devices and then when you turn them back on choose Don't Sync History and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the file with the offending history item:

~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Safari/SafariTabs.db

I deleted this file and the problem history item went away.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.

Comment: I'm going to close this as it's bumped again. If anyone needs to make a new answer, please vote to reopen if you can and then flag for moderator review. Thanks!